# In C how to handle this form of 2D array function_name(int *mat[])

Tags: c

How to print a matrix in C using this form of function: `display(int *matrix[],int rows, int cols)`??

Comment: Use 2 loops (one for row - another for column) with `printf`.

Comment: Basically don't use 2D arrays in C. Use 1D array and access them e.g. by using the macro  `#define MATRIX_ELEM(M,i,j) M[(i)*WIDTH+(j)]`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, why would you say that? Since C99, C has very good support for multidimensional arrays. In the contrary, you should never do such things by hand but let the compiler do it. It is written for such things.

Comment: Be aware that what you are using pseudo-2D arrays, here. If it is still an option and you have a C99 compiler, change your design to real 2D arrays and pass the dimensions before the array, something like `display(size_t rows, size_t cols, int matrix[rows][cols])`.

Comment: `int *matrix[]` is 100% equivalant to `int **matrix`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each method here assumes that your `matrix` variable contains an array of rows (each inner array represents a row of your matrix).

### Using pointer-to-pointer

You could do it like this:

```
void display(int** matrix,int rows, int cols) {
   int i,j;
   for(i=0; i < rows; i++) {
       for(j=0; j < cols; j++) {
           printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\r\n");
   }
}
```

To initialize the matrix, you could do something like this:

```
int** matrix;
int i,j;
int rows = 4, columns = 2;
matrix = (int**)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(columns*sizeof(int));
for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
   for(j=0; j<2; j++) {
      matrix[i][j] = i+j;
   }
}
```

### Using 2D-arrays

You could do it like this, note that this only works with the current `C99` standard:

```
void display(int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols]) {
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(j=0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\r\n");
    }
}
```

You can call the function like this:

```
int matrix2[4][2];
for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<2; j++) {
        matrix2[i][j] = i+j;
    }
}
display(4, 2, matrix);
```

### Using 1D-array

As suggested in the comments, you can make your life much easier by simply using unbounded 1D-arrays and using a helper to access your matrix:

```
int elementAt(int matrix[], int x, int y, int columns) {
    return matrix[x*columns+y];
}

void display(int rows, int cols, int matrix[]) {
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(j=0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", elementAt(matrix, i, j, cols));
        }
        printf("\r\n");
    }
}
```

You would call this like so:

```
int matrix3[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
display(4, 2, matrix3);
```

Comment: This gives a Segmentation fault.


void display(int *matrix[],int rows,int cols)
{
int i,j;
for (i=0;i<1;i++)
{
 for (j=0;j<2;j++)
 {
  printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]);
 }
 printf("\n");
}
}

Comment: In that case, you probably didn't allocate the memory for your matrix array correctly. You didn't show us how you're doing this and like I said, I'm assuming that it contains an array of columns.

Comment: This is what I'm doing:
main.....
int arr[4][2]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
display(arr,4,2);
and then I'm calling display method in main method
display(arr,4,2);

Comment: The initialization of your array is wrong. You're initializing a 2nd-order array (array of arrays) with a first-order sequence. This is never going to work. Instead, to initialize your matrix, you would need to iterate over the rows and then initialize each row one by one. I updated the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: void display(int *[],int,int);
int main()
{
 int matrix[4][2];
 int i,j;
 for(i=0; i<4; i++) 
 {
    for(j=0; j<2; j++) 
    {
       matrix[i][j] = i+j;
     }
 }
 display(matrix,4,2);
 return 0;
}

void display(int *matrix[],int rows,int cols)
{
 int i,j;
 for(i=0; i < rows; i++) 
 {
        for(j=0; j < cols; j++) 
        {
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\r\n");
    }
}
this is the whole code and still Segmentation fault

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I corrected my answer again. You can't pass an unbound 2nd-order array like that into a C-function. Either you need to know its dimensions or you need to pass it as a pointer. I edited my answer to pass the array as a pointer

Comment: Sure you can, the problem is that you seem to be mixing up arrays of pointers and 2D arrays. These are not the same.

Comment: You're right, but it only works with `C99` by passing in the size of the array to the function. I was testing with an earlier version and that's why it failed for me. Thanks for the precision

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

```
 int a[5][5];

 for ( i=0; i < rows ; i ++) 
      for ( j=0; j < cols ; j++ ) 
             printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
```